# Wondering what the overall quantity of beer will be ..?

Tags: beer

i am just wondering if i have ..

- 1 KG of DME
- 2 KG ( rice malt syrup )

how many liters of beer i can make out of them if i wanted to make a good full bodied beer ?

Thanks ![image][image]

Comment: Try BrewTarget, BeerSmith or other similar tool.

Comment: You will not get a full bodied beer by using that much rice syrup.  One of the purposes of rice syrup is to thin the body.

Comment: so can't i use it at all ?

Comment: yeah, you can probably use it, but it won't be full bodied and with a 2:1 rice:barley ratio it won't taste a lot like beer  ETA:  I just noticed that there's barley in the rice syrup...what the heck, go ahead.  I wouldn't expect much though.

Answer (score 1):

Quick check and you should get 1048 if you drop it all in a 5gallon about 25l batch. Would seem a reasonable gravity. Please report back on how it brews up.